# JSON Lint Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

Tags: json

I'm getting error on a large JSON file which i parsed using scraping software.

Here is the error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1210:
...enceNumber": 0  }}{  "url": "http://a
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'
```

My code where i'm getting error

```
    "sequenceNumber": 0
  }
}{
  "url": "http://anidb.info/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=12994",
  "result": {
```

Comment: Indeed, that is invalid JSON. This typically happens when several *valid* JSON parts are concatenated into one big *invalid* JSON. There should be a comma between each `}{` sequence.

Comment: Did you create that JSON yourself?

Comment: not yet, i did not created it myself, but i tried by using , between each },{ this way still im getting error @trincot

Comment: But the error messages are quite clear. It tells you exactly which character was wrong, and what could be valid there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by doing two things:

1. added `[` at start of file and `]` at the end of file.
2. added `,` between `},{`

my new code exaple

```
[
...
    "sequenceNumber": 0
  }
},{
  "url": "http://anidb.info/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=12994",
  "result": {
...
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the attention. @trincot